# Convert number into culture specific

Tags: c#, localization, number-formatting, cultureinfo, culture

I have a number like  `202667.4`. I want to convert this to number *based on culture*.

For Ex:

> In "de"(German) the number should be in **202.667,40**.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you want to represent existing number (say, `double`) in culture specific format, try *formatting*:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings

```
double source = 202667.4;

// "n"  - ... group separators, and a decimal separator with optional negative sign  
// "de" - German culture
string result = source.ToString("n", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("de"));

Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Outcome

```
202.667,40
```

If you are given a `string` and you want a number, put `Parse` (`TryParse`):

```
string data = "202.667,40";

double result = double.Parse(data, CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("de"));

Console.WriteLine(data.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```

If you don't want to specify the culture each time you work with formatting, you can set the culture as a *current* one:

```
CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("de");

...

double source = 202667.4;

Console.WriteLine($"{source:n}");
```

Comment: Tanks @Dmitry, It's worked. But, I want output as a number not as string. Any way to do this?

Comment: @Manikandan Ram: number is always the same, but its representation (as a string) can *vary* (i.e. we want `202667.4` be represented in German culture with group and decimal separators), that's why we use formatting.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Culture info while parsing number into German format

Try with this approach:

```
string.Format(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("de-DE"), "{0:000,000.00}", <your number>)
```

for example:

```
 string result = string.Format(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("de-DE"), "{0:000,000.00}", 202667.4)
```

Comment: I have tried. But, it’s not worked.
System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("de");

double num = Double.Parse("202667.4", culture);

2026674.0

What I’m missing?

Comment: I don't understand your comment @ManikandanRam, a `double` has no format. Formatting comes into play when interpreting a string to parse it, but it looks like it parsed your number string correctly, and it comes into play when formatting a string, which you don't do in the comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to convert variables to different cultures:

```
int MyInt = 100;
string MyString = MyInt.ToString("C",CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("de-DE"));
MessageBox.Show(MyString);
```

If you want to build all programs with a German format you can this code at your main class:

```
using System.Globalization;`

Application.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("de-DE");`
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 System.Globalization.CultureInfo EnglishCulture = new 
System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-EN");
System.Globalization.CultureInfo GermanCulture = new 
System.Globalization.CultureInfo("de-de");
```

neccesary transformation,

```
double val;
if(double.TryParse("65,89875", System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Float, 
GermanCulture,  out val))
{
string valInGermanFormat = val.ToString(GermanCulture);
string valInEnglishFormat = val.ToString(EnglishCulture);
 }

if(double.TryParse("65.89875", System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Float, 
EnglishCulture,  out val))
{
string valInGermanFormat = val.ToString(GermanCulture);
string valInEnglishFormat = val.ToString(EnglishCulture);
 }
```