# C# parse int from different locale

Tags: c#, .net-core

I know, there are other questions like this
e.g. [Convert number into culture specific](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47323838/convert-number-into-culture-specific)

But I am having a hard time and even the answer doesn't work for me. Still getting 
System.FormatException: 'Input string was not in a correct format.'

My current/system locale is de and I am parsing an en int. Whatever I tried so far (including answers from previous quesions, does not work.

So, what am I missing?

```
            string numberStr = "1,111"; // one thousand one hundred eleven

            //int result = int.Parse(numberStr);
            //int result = int.Parse(numberStr, CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US").NumberFormat);
            //int result = int.Parse(numberStr, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            //int result = int.Parse(numberStr, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat);
            //int result = int.Parse(numberStr, CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-UK").NumberFormat);
            int result = int.Parse(numberStr, CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en"));

            Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Comment: That answer is for *doubles*,that's why the code works immediatelly. With ints, it looks like the default NumberStyles doesn't include thousand separators

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your problem is simply that `int.Parse(string)` and `int.Parse(string, IFormatProvider)` don't allow a thousands separator.

You can see this in the Remarks section of [the doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.parse?view=netframework-4.8#System_Int32_Parse_System_String_):

> The `s` parameter contains a number of the form:
>
> [ws][sign]digits[ws]

You can however, use the [`int.Parse(string, NumberStyles)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.parse?view=netframework-4.8#System_Int32_Parse_System_String_System_Globalization_NumberStyles_), overload, which lets you specify [`NumberStyles`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.numberstyles?view=netframework-4.8).

If we peek at [the source for `int.Parse(string)`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/int32.cs,119), we can see that it effectively calls `int.Parse(string, NumberStyles.Integer)`.

If you look at the docs for [`NumberStyles`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.numberstyles?view=netframework-4.8), we want `Integer`, but also `AllowThousands`. We don't want to go as far as `Number`, because that includes `AllowDecimalPoint`, and integers can't have decimal points.

```
int result = int.Parse("1,111", NumberStyles.Integer | NumberStyles.AllowThousands);
```

You probably *also* want to specify a culture, because the thousands separator depends on culture (e.g. German uses `.` as the thousands separator). The invariant culture uses `,`, as does `en`:

```
int result = int.Parse(
    "1,111", 
    NumberStyles.Integer | NumberStyles.AllowThousands,
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 5):

If you allow thousands separators, it will work:

```
int.Parse("1,111", NumberStyles.AllowThousands, CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en"));
// 1111
```